# Is it unusual to stack modulation effects like chorus/phasers/doublers?

Tags: modulation, autotune

I mean have a vocal track with two different types of doublers on it stacked in series. Usually I wouldnt do this but it sounds ok to me.

Is it very unusual (or amateurish) to stack modulated delay effects like chorus/phaser/flanger/doubler effects
in series on the same vocal track?
(Not in parallel - and I'm not talking about long delays like slaps or 1/8th notes)?

Comment: Brian Stoltz (Neville Brothers, Funky Meters) frequently combined univibe and (MXR) flanger to create lush chorus/rotary sound for his guitar when playing with the Funky Meters. It’s definitely a thing that is done in places. Multiple delays and/or multiple reverbs are also used quite often on a single signal when mixing.

Comment: It might depend of what the style is. Folk music… I'd give it a miss. EDM, you're still about two FX short ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not at all unusual or wrong. You might want to have one effect sweeping at a different rate to another one to give a more complex motion, or combine the filtering effect of two 'doublers' to give a particular frequency response.

One thing you might need to watch for, especially if you have two 'doublers' set up in similar ways, is the modulations coming into /out of phase and causing strong reinforcements or cancellations of the signal.

You also might want to try the mix on a few different systems (including a mono mix) to make sure that the vocals aren't getting cancelled out too much.